# Should I get rid of the filesystem at /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs?

Tags: 10.10, filesystem

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10. When I run `df -h`, I get:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             285G   20G  251G   8% /
none                  1.5G  264K  1.5G   1% /dev
none                  1.5G  176K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.5G   96K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/lock
none                  285G   20G  251G   8% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
```

Is it a good idea to try to get rid off the last item `debugfs`?

Comment: Can you indent the output with four spaces? This way, we can see it   formatted nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything to get rid of, other than the dangling entry in /etc/mtab.  debugfs is a virtual filesystem like /proc; it does not actually exist on disk.  There is a bug somewhere in the boot process where it is unmounted, but /etc/mtab is not updated, so it still shows it in df.  Since nothing is actually mounted there, df gets the size information from your / filesystem.